# Capitalizing letters that follow colons using 'replace-regexp-in-string'

Tags: regular-expressions, replace, string

I want to capitalize letters that follow colons.  Here is the code:

```el
(replace-regexp-in-string ": \w" 'upcase ": really")
```

The result I expected is `: Really`.  Instead I get `: really`.

Similarly, this also doesn't work:

```el
(replace-regexp-in-string ": [:alpha:]" 'upcase ": really")
```

But this works:

```el
(replace-regexp-in-string ": r" 'upcase ": really")
```

And this, too:

```el
(replace-regexp-in-string ": [:alpha:]" 'upcase ": alright")
```

My `LANG` environment variable is set to `en_US.UTF-8`.

Comment: In the first example you are missing a backslash and in the second a set of braces. I.e. these regexps don't match the provided string.

Comment: And I'm pretty sure your last example didn't work ☺

Comment: @Malabarba, there was an error in the example.  I fixed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to double the backslash in a Lisp string:

```el
(replace-regexp-in-string ": \\w" #'upcase ": really")
```

See the Elisp manual, node [`Syntax for Strings`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-for-Strings.html).

And a char class has chars inside `[]`, so put `[:alpha:]` inside `[]`.

```el
(replace-regexp-in-string ": [[:alpha:]]" #'upcase ": really")
```

See the Elisp manual, node [`Regexp Special`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regexp-Special.html).